# display data from one window textareas into other window textarea in EclipseWindowBuilder

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, textarea, windowbuilder

I am new to Java
I created a conversion software for metric units and now I want to create new window for logging the output of converted units from one Window text areas into one text area in another window [Picture of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFM3A.png)
Both Windows are one application

What code would I need to put in there to display this in another window text area

```
JButton btnConvert = new JButton("Convert");
    btnConvert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            double numCM,sumCM;
            double numKM,sumKM;
            double numMIL,sumMIL;

            try {

                //startCM//
                numCM = Double.parseDouble(textFieldenter.getText());
                sumCM = numCM*100;
                textFieldcm.setText(Double.toString(sumCM));

                //endCM//

                //startKILOMETERS//
                numKM = Double.parseDouble(textFieldenter.getText());
                sumKM = numKM*0.001;
                textFieldkm.setText(Double.toString(sumKM));
                //endKILOMETERS//

                //startMILES//
                numMIL = Double.parseDouble(textFieldenter.getText());
                sumMIL = numMIL*0.000621;
                textFieldmil.setText(Double.toString(sumMIL));
                //endMILES//


            }

            catch (Exception e1) {

                JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(btnConvert, "Value etered is incorrect");

            }


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method JTextField.getText() over your JTextFields and store its value into a String variable, then pass it to the JTextArea using the method append(String str) and put a line break at the end with `/n`

Read the API for these classes to learn more about its methods and how to use them [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)

It would be something like this

```
String record = "";

record = textFieldcm.getText()+" "+textFieldkm.getText()+" "+textFieldmil.getText();

JTextArea.append(record+"\n");
```

Comment: I have applied this code but I get error when I insert 'append' it just shows rename the file

Comment: Thanks for the links

Comment: Check you are using a valid reference to the JTextArea and passing a valid argument to it. The syntax is JTextAreaName.append(String str);

Comment: this code needs to be applied to the button convert or my other text Area? I put it just above the 'try'

Comment: Yes it must be applied on a valid reference variable to a JTextArea